# Mapstruct - how to create generated code to add when we have many to many entity

Tags: spring, mapping, many-to-many, mapstruct

I try use mapstruct to save my DTO to entity. In the basic relations I had no problem with the generated code, but needs help with the generation in the relation many to many.

My entity:
Hero

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "hero")
public class Hero extends Identifiable<Long> {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID", nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "NAME", nullable = false, length = 150)
    private String Name;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
    @JoinTable(
            name="HERO_MOVIE",
            joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="ID_HERO", referencedColumnName="ID"),
            inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="ID_MOVIE", referencedColumnName="ID")
    )
    private List<Movie> movies;
```

Movie:

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "Movie")
public class Movie extends Identifiable<Long> {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID", nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "Name", nullable = false, length = 20)
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "CODE", nullable = false, length = 2)
    private String code;
```

HERO_MOVIE:

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "HERO_MOVIE")
public class HeroMovie extends Identifiable<Long> {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID", nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "ID_HERO")
    private Hero hero;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "ID_MOVIE")
    private Movie movie;

}
```

And my HeroSaveDTO. I have list of moviesIds and I need create new Hero and after that HeroMovie

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class HeroSaveDTO implements IdentifiableDTO {
    private Long id;
    private String nazwa;
    private List<Long> movieIds;
}
```

I need to fix my code to mapstruct dto mapping target entity and save this.

Comment: Can you post your current mapper, and the generated  implementation code?

Answer (score 0):

you have to create an interface for mapping Hero Class to HeroDTO and in the next step you should override mapping method for field the moviesId

```java
@Mapper
public interface HeroMapper {

    @Mapping(source = "movies", target = "postIds", qualifiedByName = "mapMovieIds")
    HeroDTO toHeroDTO(Hero post);

    @Named(value = "mapMovieIds")
    default List<Integer> mapMovieIds(List<Movie> movies) {
        List<Integer> integers = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Movie movie : movies) {
            integers.add(movie.getId());
        }
        return integers;
    }
}
```